# Yii: Make dropDownList readonly/disabled in form

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to make `DropDownList` readonly or disable in form for update condition but my code is not working ...

```
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'sem_id', CHtml::listData(Sem::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'title'/*, array("disabled" => "disabled")*/ , array('readonly' => 'readonly') ));
```

**Error: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members**

Answer (score 5):

First thing is you should `dropDownList` instead of `dropDownListRow`. Also you forgot to use `)` after `'title'` And you should use `"disabled" => "disabled"` instead of `'readonly' => 'readonly'`. I don't think they have a readonly attribute in html tags.

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'sem_id', CHtml::listData(Sem::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'title'), array("disabled" => "disabled"));
```

This can make disabled dropdown list, but note that you can't relay on html attributes. Because the users can remove this attribute easily and can change dropdown value. So you need to have a control on your server.

Comment: Thank you @hamed, it works for me. I used yiibooster, so used dropDownListRow insteda of dropDownList. :)

Comment: It disabled the dropdowns but also set the data in it to null.

Answer (score 3):

Working example of Yii 2 dropdown disable:

```
<?=
  $form->field($model, 'customer_status')->dropDownList([
    '0' => 'Requested',
    '1' => 'Registered',
    '3' => 'Un-Rgistered',
    '2' => 'Disabled'
  ], ['disabled' => 'disabled'])
?>
```

Comment: <?php $form->field($model, 'customer_status')->dropDownList(['disabled'=>'disabled']) ?>